# Relation between second-order derivatives and corner solutions

Tags: utility, optimization

Imagine I have the simple maximisation programme:

$$\max_{x,y}U(x,y)$$
$$\text{subject to: } B=x+y$$

$U(\cdot)$ satisfies the usual properties: it is increasing and concave in both arguments. This amounts to maximising:

$$U(x,B-x)\quad(1)$$

Here, $x$ and $y$ must be greater or equal to zero. Denote by $x^*$ the value of $x$ solving:

$$\partial_1U-\partial_2U=0$$

Having the second-order derivative of expression (1) strictly negative ensures we $x^*$ is a local maxima. But is it also a necessary and/or sufficient condition for having no corner solutions (i.e., no cases where $x^*=0$)?

In other words, is this statement true?:

$$\partial_{11} U +\partial_{22} U-2\partial_{12}U<0\Leftrightarrow x^*>0$$

If not, what are the necessary and sufficient solutions for having no corner solutions? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Second order condition alone does not guarantee interior solution; you'll also need the the first order condition $\nabla U = \vec0$.

Comment: Thanks @HerrK. - First Order Conditions guarantee I have a critical point. SOC tells me whether it is a local maxima or a minima. My question is about the necessary and sufficient conditions for having an interior solution. Let me change the wording to reflect your comment.

Comment: With the objective function being increasing and concave, the FOC and SOC together form a set of necessary and sufficient condition for interior solution. In particular, the solution is interior due to the condition $\nabla U = \vec 0$. Have a look at the [Arrow-Enthoven sufficiency theorem](https://www.econometricsociety.org/publications/econometrica/browse/article-comments/1961/10/01/quasi-concave-programming/comment/ECTA17014.pdf) for a more nuanced exposition.